# has_many association...class id not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many

How can I write the code below so that it passes the user.id.  Given what I have, it throws Class id not found error.  (User has many fights.  And Fight belongs to user. User can either be a challenger in the fight, or a challengee in the other.)

```
has_many :fight_wins, :class_name => 'Fight', :foreign_key => 'challenger_id or challengee_id', 
  :conditions => ["(challenger_id = ? and challenger_won = ?) or (challengee_id = ? and challenger_won = ?)", self.id, true, self.id, false]
```

Comment: Why can't you use a named_scope or scope (for rails3) to handle what you are trying to do? Then it would be a simple User has_many :fights and Fights belongs_to :user.

Comment: Yup, you can! But I'd like to know the solution to the approach above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `finder_sql` option for complex `has_many` conditions:

```
has_many :fight_wins, :class_name => 'Fight', :finder_sql =>
      '#{sanitize_sql_array(
          "SELECT f.* 
           FROM   fights AS f 
           WHERE  (f.challenger_id = ? AND f.challenger_won = ?) OR 
                  (f.challengee_id = ? AND f.challenger_won = ?)
          ", id, true, id, false)}'
```

Comment: when i run this, it's saying id not defined local variable or method